# How To Change A Unix Timestamp In The Future To Seconds Remaining

Tags: php, time

I am trying to create a javascript countdown timer;

I have a string that is in the format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS .

This could be any time up to 6 months in the future.

What would be the best way to go about getting the time remaining in seconds from now until the future time.  This could be implemented in PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can use `strtotime`, which takes a string representation of a date and returns the unix timestamp.

Then use `microtime` to get the current unix timestamp, and find the difference. This will be the number of milliseconds remaining, so divide it by 1000 to get it in seconds.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

This should work:

```
$currentTime = explode(" ", microtime());
$currentTime = $currentTime[1];
$futureTime = strtotime("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"); // insert your date here
$timeRemaining = ($futureTime - $currentTime) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you getting this string-based timestamp? A unix timestamp is actually already "number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00". That looks like a native MySQL date string.

If it is coming out of MySQL, you can convert it to a unix-style timestamp with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, e.g.

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(datetimefield) ...
```

and then convert it to a Javascript timestamp by multiplying by 1000 (JS timestamps have the same epoch, but in milliseconds).

If you're stuck in PHP, you can go quick/dirt with

```
$timestamp = strtotime($time_string);
$js_timestamp = $timestamp * 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,  What I am doing is setting a closing date for a competition that I am running on my site. I am entering the values into the mysql table in the same format as the unix timestamp

Comment: A unix timestamp is just a number: the number of seconds since jan 1/1970. e.g. right now as I'm typing this the unix timestamp is 1326397358 on my local machine.

Comment: @user866190 Usually you just store the number in the database rather than its string representation. Can you do this or are you stuck with legacy code/existing records?

Comment: Thanks Matt your solution worked perfectly.. I just need to get rid of the divide pate of the expression.. thanks